# Android Popup weird behaviour in Scroll View

Tags: android, scrollview, android-popupwindow

I have a Popup window Anchored to a Text View

```
popUpWindow.showAsDropDown(textView, final_placement_width, final_placement_height);
```

and when ever I scroll down this TextView will move up along with the popup window.

The problem is if i scroll down too much the PopUp Window will not only show ontop of the Content Window, but also will re-position itself to a new Scroll view at the bottom.

How do set the Popup so that it will stay on top of the TextView number 1 and behind the Purple content window no matter how far down i scroll.

[image]

Edit: XML FILE: 
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testapp.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content Main xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testapp.test.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appOptions"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your `xml` file

Comment: added xml @MohammadAli thanks

Comment: you want to show your list at 1st line if u go till the end ?

Comment: yes correct, i want the popup to still be at first, don't want it to jump to bottom when scrolling

Comment: where is image of your pop up?

Comment: @willywijaya sorry if it wasn't clear, but the image is the question mark icon you see in the screenshot i have is the pop Up

Comment: so that pop up is floating action button?

Comment: no, Floating action button and PopUp are two different things. You can't see the Floating action button it's not in the screenshot